# Opencv: BoW computing SURF descriptors

Tags: python, opencv, surf, descriptor

I'm trying to do bag of words on a set of images, extracting SURF descriptors. However, I obtain the following error on the very last line of the code pasted below:

type == src2.type() && src1.cols == src2.cols && (type == CV_32F || type == CV_8U)

If I use "SIFT" instead, then everything works. But when I use "SURF", BoW cannot compute the SURF descriptors.

Is this the correct way to instantiate SURF? Am I allowed to use the cv2.NORM_L2 distance function?

```
imgs2Keypoints = {}
kmeansTrainer = cv2.BOWKMeansTrainer(10);  
for pathToImage in images:
    sift = cv2.SURF(400)
    img = cv2.imread(pathToImage)
    kp, des = sift.detectAndCompute(img, None)
    des = np.float32(des)
    kmeansTrainer.add(des)
    imgs2Keypoints[pathToImage] = kp 
vocabulary = kmeansTrainer.cluster()
bow_ext.setVocabulary(vocabulary)

surf2 = cv2.DescriptorExtractor_create("SURF")
bow_ext = cv2.BOWImgDescriptorExtractor(surf2, cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_L2))

for pathToImage in images:
    img = cv2.imread(pathToImage)
    histogram = bow_ext.compute(img, imgs2Keypoints[pathToImage])[0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

```
sift = cv2.SURF(400)
```

creates extended SURF descriptors (128 dimensional), whereas

```
surf2 = cv2.DescriptorExtractor_create("SURF")
```

creates standard SURF descriptors (64 dimensional).

A possible solution is to disable extended descriptors for the *sift* object

```
sift.extended = False
```

Edit 2:

For use with extended descriptors:

```
surf2.setBool("extended", True)
```

As for L2 norm: Yes, L2 distance is fine. As stated in [OpenCV docs](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_descriptor_matchers.html?highlight=bruteforcematcher#bfmatcher-bfmatcher):

> L1 and L2 norms are preferable choices for SIFT and SURF descriptors

Comment: I already do the img = imread(pathToImage) before I make the compute() call. I miscopied my code above -- just updated my code snipped above to reflect this. That isn't causing the compute error.